# Does Android 2.3 have any world writable directories if I have no SD card inserted?

Tags: android-2.3-gingerbread

I wrote a shell script for my rooted Android 2.3 phone, but I am afraid of losing the system stability by running it as root and making it run out of space. For this reason, I would prefer to run the script as `app_40`, but I cannot find any world writable directory when I have no SD card inserted. Is there any place where I could write the output of my script to so that it would be saved and use the phone's free internal memory space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such directory is `/data/local`.